# Try/catch & saving an ArrayList using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, exception, save, java.util.scanner

I don't understand how to code this properly. I've read all over the internet and my book and maybe I am over complicating this.

I am trying to save the arraylist to a .txt  -Obviously when I press '1' to add(studentInfo) it is giving me the exception because apparently it is what I'm telling it to do.

What I want is to add() and if the file exist then to override it or to open it and save on it again.

I apologize if this sounds confusing. I am very confused myself.

```
case 1: 
                    try{
                    addStudent(studentInfo);
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    removeStudent(studentInfo);
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    display(studentInfo);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    load(studentInfo);
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using the student database!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }

   }  



    //ADD 
    private void addStudent(ArrayList<Student> studentInfo) throws FileNotFoundException  { 


         Scanner add = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));

         while(add.hasNext()){    

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's name: ");
         String name = add.nextLine();

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's last name: ");
         String lastName = add.nextLine();

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's major: ");
         String major = add.nextLine();

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's GPA: ");
         String gpaNumber = add.nextLine();
         double gpa  = Double.parseDouble(gpaNumber);

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's UIN: ");
         String uinNumber = add.nextLine();
         int uin = Integer.parseInt(uinNumber);

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's NetID: ");
         String idName = add.nextLine();

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's age: ");
         String years = add.nextLine();
         int age = Integer.parseInt(years);

         System.out.println("\nEnter the student's gender: Female or Male ");
         String gender = add.nextLine();

         Student newStudent = new Student (name, lastName, major, gpa, uin, idName, age, gender);

         if(studentInfo.size() <10){
         studentInfo.add(newStudent);
         System.out.println("Student information saved.");
         System.out.println();
         }
         else{
            System.out.println("Database is full");
         }

         }

         add.close();


   }
```

Comment: You are just reading from file and adding to ArrayList conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you are trying to construct a new student object, input a student's information, and then write all of the students' information to a file.

`new File(students.txt)` is how you can tell Java how to work with an existing file, it can't create one, and that's what is causing your error. You can create a students.txt file if you'd like to see how your code will perform after that error is resolved.

Scanner is an input handler, not a document writer. So when your `add` Scanner is constructed using a File object, it's actually going to be reading already existing information in that file. It won't allow you to write to the file.

Furthermore, when you are using `nextLine()`, it is iterating through lines in the file, not writing (or accepting) your input.

I recommend reading up on Java File I/O. There are a lot of materials online and here on Stack Overflow. If this is a homework assignment, be careful not to use anything "cutting edge" if your teacher wants you to go by the book.